# Contenedores Docker con múltiples instancias

Tags: javascript, nodejs, rest, docker, socket

Estamos con un trabajo del máster donde tenemos un código que se ejecuta en node, el cual simula una comunicación cliente-broker-worker. El Client.js es un cliente escuchando mediante REST unas peticiones en el puerto 3000 (Las peticiones pueden son POST, donde se solicita realizar una operación matemática).

Dichas peticiones se las pasa a uno de los dos Brokers (Cola/Load balancer) a los que se conecta, estos las tratan y se las pasa a un worker especializado para que las resuelva (Tenemos workers de suma, resta, multiplicación y división) y se las envíe de vuelta al Broker y este al Cliente para finalmente mostrarlo de nuevo al Usuario desde POSTMAN.

El cliente le pasa la petición al broker mediante un socket dealer, el Broker usa dos routers, uno para escuchar/enviar mensajes del cliente y otro para escuchar/enviar mensajes al worker.

Adjunto el código donde se ven los puertos de conexión/escucha de cada parte del trabajo.

Cliente:

```
const puertoEscuchaBroker = 4000;
const puertoEscuchaBroker2=5000;
let dealer = zmq.socket("dealer");
/Definimos el sockt Router
let router = zmq.socket("router");

var identidad  = "C_"+require('os').hostname();

//Aqui se declara el ID del Dealer para traajar con el.
dealer.identity = identidad;

//Conectamos el dealer al broker1
dealer.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+puertoEscuchaBroker);
//Conectamos el dealer al broker2
dealer.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+puertoEscuchaBroker2);
```

Broker:

```
var puertoDelCliente = argumentos[2];
var puertoDelWorker = argumentos[3];

cliente.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+puertoDelCliente);
worker.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+puertoDelWorker);
```

Aquí, el puerto del cliente y del worker se le pasa como parámetro por terminal y lanzamos el código dos veces (node broker.js 4000 8000 y node broker.js 5000 8800).

Worker:

```
const brokerPort1 = 8000; 
const brokerPort2 = 8800;
deal.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+brokerPort1);
deal.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:"+brokerPort2);
```

Bien, funcionar nos funciona correctamente en local, pero ahora, debemos crear una imagen en Docker para conseguir correrlo en cualquier dispositivo y no sabemos como preparar el DockerFile ni el DockerCompose para que no haya problemas a la hora de definir los puertos a los que escucha cada una de las partes ni sabemos como definir 3 instancias de la cola (Ahora tenemos 2) y 4 del worker (Tiene que haber de suma, resta, multiplicación y división)ya que es lo que nos exige el trabajo.

> **PD:** Es nuestra primera consulta en StackOverflow y entendemos que pueden haber cosas que no se entiendan y demás, pero cualquier cosa puedo editar la pregunta para dejar las cosas más claras si así lo creéis conveniente.